Convert HDF image to tiff in python
I just need to convert HDF image to tiff in python, but I have no programming knowledge. Do you have a script ready or a tutorial?
I used NASA's HEG Tools, but it is obsolete.
I have little programming knowledge.
I need a script or tutorial with a step-by-step guide to extract the GPP image from the MODIS product (MOD17A2H) to tiff format.

Looks like gdal_translate can do it for you without needing any code https://gis.stackexchange.com/q/395417/207216

We'll use libraries h5py.
h5py documentation: https://docs.h5py.org/en/latest/
Here's a Python script that extracts the GPP band and saves it as a TIFF:
# Import libraries
import h5py
from osgeo import gdal

# Define file paths
hdf_file = "path/to/your/MOD17A2H.hdf"
tiff_file = "gpp.tiff"

# Open HDF file
with h5py.File(hdf_file, "r") as f:
  # Get GPP dataset (path may vary depending on file structure)
  gpp_data = f["MOD_Grid/Data Fields/GPP"]

# Convert data to numpy array (adjust axis if needed)
gpp_array = gpp_data[...]

# Open output TIFF file with GDAL
driver = gdal.GetDriverByName("GTiff")
dataset = driver.Create(tiff_file, gpp_array.shape[1], gpp_array.shape[0], 1, gdal.GDT_Float32)  # Adjust data type if needed

# Set origin (adjust based on your data)
dataset.SetGeoTransform([0, 0.006, 0, 56, 0, -0.006])  # Replace with your geotransform values

# Write data to TIFF file
dataset.RasterWrite(0, 0, gpp_array.shape[1], gpp_array.shape[0], gpp_array, band_list=[1])

# Close the files
dataset.FlushCache()
dataset = None


Thank you very much for your reply! I would be very grateful if you could analyze the error that is occurring below:

OSError                                   Traceback (most recent call last)
 in <cell line: 10>()
8
9 # Open HDF file
---> 10 with h5py.File(hdf_file, "r") as f:
11   # Get GPP dataset (path may vary depending on file structure)
12   gpp_data = f["MOD_Grid/Data Fields/GPP"]

1 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/h5py/_hl/files.py in make_fid(name, mode, userblock_size, fapl, fcpl, swmr)
229       if swmr and swmr_support:
230             flags |= h5f.ACC_SWMR_READ
--> 231         fid = h5f.open(name, flags, fapl=fapl)
232     elif mode == 'r+':
233         fid = h5f.open(name, h5f.ACC_RDWR, fapl=fapl)
h5py/_objects.pyx in h5py._objects.with_phil.wrapper()
h5py/_objects.pyx in h5py._objects.with_phil.wrapper()
h5py/h5f.pyx in h5py.h5f.open()
OSError: Unable to open file (file signature not found)
Kind regards,
Fran
